# show which source files are being compiled

Tags: maven

Is there any way to see which source files are being compiled by maven?

I was hoping `--debug` would do the trick, but if I run `mvn --debug package`, I only get:

> [INFO] Compiling 3 source files to ...
>
> [DEBUG] ttcl changed run compileInProcessWithProperClassloader

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My build is stalling. I think there might be an infinite loop with auto generated code re-triggering the build. I'd like to see which source file is causing the stall.

Comment: Where is your build staling? In your IDE? on command line? On your CI server? furthermore which JDK, Maven version etc. full log output could help....

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you may be able to see which files have been compiled after the fact using something like `find <project>/target/classes -type f -iname '*.class' -exec stat -c '%y %n' {} ';' | sort -r`